# Does Firebase.initializeApp() require network connection?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm building a flutter app, and in order to integrate Firebase to it, I have to run Firebase.initializeApp(), but I'd like to know if it that method won't work if the phone is not online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not require a network connection.  It is just establishing configuration for Firebase SDKs.  Those SDKs will require network.